# Reduce database write on notification system or change approbate database?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-design, notifications

We have a web app which requires to send lots of notifications to users (over `1,000,000` notifications per day). We use [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#database-notifications) and MySQL for the database.

I loop through a group of users send notifications and save it to the database. Let's say if I want to send a group of `1000` users. The data will be written to the DB `1000` time. As I said, we have over `1,000,000` notifications per day, which take so many resources.

What's the appropriate way to approach this problem?

I should change to a new database system like MongoDB or I should redesign the notification table schema and the way I save to DB?

The following is my notification table schema.

[image: Laravel notification table structure]

PS:: I need to save every notification to DB and need to show to users. Can't skip this part.

Comment: Is the notification content same for all users or vary from user to user?

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending the same content for all users, I would suggest the following approach.

DATABASE SCHEMA

> notification_contents (id, content, created_by, created_at, updated_at)
>
> user_notifications (id, user_id, notification_id, status, created_at,
>   updated_at)

When there is a new notification is to be sent, 
Insert it into the notification_contents table. You can use placeholders in your content if you want to customize the content. For example Username or email

Then loop through the users and insert them into the `user_notifications` table with the `user_id` and `notification_id`. Initially set a `status` flag as zero if you want to implement a queuing mechanism for this.

Then write a cron job to take `x` number of users from the  `user_notifications` table and send the content to them. You can join user_notifications with `notification_contents` to get the content for email.

Set the `status` flag to one once the notification is sent.

Answer (score 1):

Shrink the dataset.

- Use ascii for UUIDs.  Do you really need a UUID?
- Compress UUIDs into `BINARY(16)`.  (This won't completely solve the scalability nightmare that UUIDs lead to, but it will help some.)
- Use ENUM for types and status, not long VARCHARs.
- What is the difference between the two "types"?
- Do you need 8-byte BIGINT?
- There are 3 TIMESTAMPs, do you need more than one?

I don't see anything like `user_id`??